# Best practice to deploy wso2 esb policies

Tags: deployment, wso2, esb, shared, remote-registry

I have setup an ESB cluster using jdbc connections to ms sql databases for local and remotely mounted config and gov registries. 1x mgt and 2xworker

Our .car file contains some ws-security policy artifacts which go to config. When I deploy to mgt it deploys OK. I have SVN dep sync setup to the cluster and when it picks up the .car it starts to deploy on the worker but fails when loading the policy files into conf. It is trying to duplicate the policy in the shared conf and fails - of course that is right but; how should I deploy these 'shared' artifacts when a .car file is distributed by svn? I need to be able to control the deploy properly. The only way I can see is via the dev studio which is terrible for our change management practice.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend multiple solutions. You can decide what to choose from them.

1. Since you have only 2 worker nodes, you can get rid of (disable) deployment synchronization and deploy the car files to all the nodes. I believe you have some automated process, so it wont be a problem to deploy to all nodes. While doing so, modify your project to bundle the policies to a separate car file and the services to another. When deploying, you deploy the policies only to management node and the services to all nodes.
2. Second option is to, add the policies to local registry. i.e. Not the config registry, not the governance registry. Then, when you deploy the car to the management node, it will add the policies to local registry of the management node. When the car file is dep-synced, worker nodes will deploy them and they will add the policies to their local registry. This will avoid the worker nodes trying to add the policies to the same location.

By going through the question, I felt you have external databases to the local registry too. But, its not necessary. You can use the internal H2 database for the local registry. H2 databases sometimes get corrupted. If such a thing happens, all you have to do is, delete the H2 database and restart the server with -Dsetup option. Having an external DB is fine. But, thats an overkill.

Comment: Thanks for your response. These are the options we came up with too.

Comment: So, did you guys decide on an option?

Comment: I determined that the error message I received on deploy can be ignored. the policy causes the deployer to try insert the user in to the user store on each cluster node. the mgt server works, the worker all throw the error. I live with that knowing why it happens and maybe it will be fixed in the future by wso2